# OpenSSL SYSCALL returned=5 for microsoft.com

Tags: ruby, openssl

I have this strange issue that I'm trying to connect to SSL service of major websites using Ruby script something like below:

```
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new(:TLSv1_2)
soc = TCPSocket.new("microsoft.com",443)
c = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(soc,ctx)
c.connect
```

Most of the site has no issue but I cannot seems to get any success result when connecting to microsoft.com. 
Using Ruby will hit the error as following:

```
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
```

Moving from Ruby to JRuby will hit error output "Socket closed" points to here:

```
org/jruby/ext/openssl/SSLSocket.java:218:in `connect'
```

If I check with browser which has no issue connecting to microsoft.com 443, the cipher is:

[image]

If check the OpenSSL ciphers list the algo as in the picture above seems is the first on the list of OpenSSL cipher.

[image]

Anything I done wrong or any extra steps is needed to make the connection successful? So far I only found Microsoft.com though for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if I change the destination from microsoft.com to www.microsoft.com, the code actually able to connect without exception.

Probably the microsoft.com end point may not be a standard SSL server instead just a routing engine?

Just put this here in case someone hit the same issue.